# Issue in Business Events and Notification Functionality on my transaction screen

Tags: acumatica, acumatica-kb

I have one transaction screen there I have header and child grid.
I want to create business event for some field of header and child grid,  Notification will be triggered when the user updates/changes on these specific fields.

Its working for header field but I am not getting option for child grid.
Please suggest or help....is there any restriction for child grid.